# How to add a new arbitrary private IP to instance in AWS EC2 or replace a previous one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an Ubuntu instance in AWS. I assigned an IP address from which I can connect to the instance from outside using PuTTY. Now I've changed my location and my IP address is different so I cannot connect to the instance with PuTTY any more. I'm trying to add another IP address (my current IP) to the instance network settings but for some reason AWS says it cannot accept the address:

> IP Address not in Subnet

[image]

What does it mean? Why does it require an address in Subnet?

My questions are:

How to bypass it? or

How to change settings so that it could accept any arbitrary IP I provede? or

How to include any arbitrary IP into the Subnet of addresses? or

How can I just change previous initial address to a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing, so I'll list my assumptions as I go along.

> I assigned an IP address from which I can connect to the instance from outside using PuTTY

Are you talking about Elastic IP, and connecting to the instance from the internet? If so, it is irrelevant to being able to assign **private** IP.

> Now I've changed my location

What does it mean? The location of EC2 instance? Like, a different region or something?

> my IP address is different
>   The IP of the instance, right? So, why can't you connect to this new IP?

The bottom line, you can add another private IP on the same subnet. That will not allow you to connect to a diiferent private IP, if you can't connect to original IP. If you are trying to do something different, please clarify!

Comment: 1) Did I say "I've changed the location of the instance"? I've changed my location - I've moved to other country, got local SIM card and am trying to connect the instance using local mobile internet.
2) When you set up a instance for the first time AWS asks from which IP you will connect to the instance. I do not have any idea if it is EIP or not. It is something that AWS sets by default - it takes your current IP.

Comment: "from which" IP you can connect is indeed controlled by security groups and have nothing to do with Private IP (which is the IP of the instance itself). Glad you figured it all out :)

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found the reason of an issue. It has nothing to do with private IP addresses.

"Security groups" are responsible for connection to the instance from outside (from internet using PuTTY). Since my IP has changed I have to reflect it in settings for the instance. See the "Security groups" of your instance and then select the appropriate to adjust:

[image]

In PuTTY:

Host name (or IP address) field: `ubuntu@Public DNS or Public IP of your instance`

Connection > SSH > Auth: use `ssh2dsa.ppk` or `ssh2rsa.ppk`, both seems to work fine